# TextInputEditText not accepting phone number when locale is in Hindi

Tags: android, locale, android-textinputlayout, android-textinputedittext

When locale changed to Hindi language, app not accepting inputs from softinput keyboard. Following code is working fine for English. Please let me know where its went wrong.

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
                android:id="@+id/farmer_phone_number_layout"
                style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/dimen_10"
                android:hint="@string/mobile_number"
                android:inputType="phone"
                app:endIconMode="clear_text"
                app:errorEnabled="true"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">
                <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                    android:id="@+id/farmer_phone_number_edt"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:digits="@string/input_digits"
                    android:imeOptions="actionDone"
                    android:inputType="phone"
                    android:maxLength="@integer/max_length_mobile_number_at_india"
                    android:textColor="@color/black" />
            </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

Using the  below code, I am trying to change the locale of the app.

```
public static Context updateResources(Context context, String countryCode) {

    Locale locale;
    locale = new Locale(countryCode.toLowerCase());
    Configuration conf = context.getResources().getConfiguration();
    conf.locale = locale;
    Locale.setDefault(locale);

    conf.setLayoutDirection(conf.locale);
    context.getResources().updateConfiguration(conf, context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
    return context;
}
```

Comment: What does ``@string/input_digits`` contains?

Comment: <string name="input_digits">0123456789</string>  @OMI Shah

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By Rajan.Kali answer, On removing the following statement app working fine.

```
     `android:digits="@string/input_digits" `
```

android:inputType="phone"  is working fine in Hindi locale.

Comment: that's what I was going to suggest you to remove that line.

Answer (score 1):

I guess when `inputType` is `phone`, it only accepts digits `'0'..'9'`, `'+'`, `'*'` and  `'#'`, which comes under standard ASCII, to support `Locale` for `phone`, better to remove `inputType=phone` and validate user input for `numbers` in your own `Locale`.